# is it possible to fix html that has unescaped < and > characters?

Tags: c#, html

For example if I have this html:

```
<div>this is a test < text</div>
```

the < after the test is an error and the right html should be

```
<div>this is a test &lt; text</div>
```

But I have a lot of html files that by error were not encoded and i need fix this error so i can parse them later.  The original source of data is not available so the only option is to fix this html I have.

Well, the sames applies to the > character and to text that has both < and > characters Like "<2000> - <2004>".  I would like to hear ideas for algorithms or libraries that can help me.  Thanks.

Note: the html sample above is a sample and the work should be done on big html files.

Comment: That isn't actually an error. HTML is allowed to have an unencoded < character if it is followed by a space.

Comment: this is actually pretty nice fact that i didnt know :)

Comment: and what about the rules for the > character? how is it allowed in html unescaped?

Comment: XHTML is not allowed to have them though.

Comment: @Karim `>` doesn't have to be escaped anywhere in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

identify and map locations of all known tags, like `<div>` and `</a>`.
Replace < and > everywhere outside the map you built in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

1) For all known html tags, replace <> with some other characters like {{{ and }}}. You can use regex more or less like this:

```
Regex.Replace(source,"</?((b|a|i|table|td|all|other|known|html|tags)( [^>]*))>","{{{$1}}}");
```

2) replace < with < and > with >

3) Replace {{{ with < and }}} with >

Answer (score 0):

Using a "relaxed" HTML parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for .NET would be a nice fit. You grab the tree as interpreted by the library, and then, in each node value, replace < and > for their proper counterparts.

See here for an example: [Iron python, beautiful soup, win32 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118654/iron-python-beautiful-soup-win32-app/170856#170856)

Comment: i dont think this will be possible , since replacing the < and > in each node will actually replace the child nodes and in the end i will be having a single body with big string of escaped childs

Comment: Nope, that won't happen as the tree is built based on recognized tags, and the actual tags are not modified with the node values. But feel free to use a more tedious and error prone approach :)

Answer (score 0):

A slow way to do it would be to treat each HTML file as an XML file.  Then parse through each one of the nodes of that XML file and do a Server.HTMLEnocde on the contents of the node.  Since HTML is just a defined set of XML this should work.

Comment: this wnt be possible since this html wont be considered as a valid xml. even if using tools like htmlagility pack then its not valid since it will treat this unescaped < as tags